# Distribute N apple and M orange among (N+M) children in such a way that, minimum numbers of pairs of children can have different fruits in a pair.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, permutations, combinations, recreational-mathematics

I have **N** apples and **M** oranges and few random pairs of **(N+M)** children.

Distribute **N** apple and **M** orange among **(N+M)** children in such a way that, minimum numbers of pairs of children can have different fruits in a pair.

For better understanding lets take an example:

Ex 1) 2 apples and 1 orange and children=(2+1)=3
      Given pairs of children are: (1,2) (2,3)
 Now if i give an apple to 1 and 3 and orange to 2, then i will have **two pairs** with different fruits in a pair. i.e (apple,orange) (orange,apple)

But if i give an apple to 1 and 2 and orange to 3, then i will have **only one pair** with different fruits in a pair. i.e (apple,apple) (apple,orange).

So answer here is **1 pair** which is minimum.

**Note**:
Number of pairs can be anything but >0 and <= nCr(n=no. of children and r=2)

Comment: Don't you mean $N+M$ instead of $N+m$, in the first sentence? And another time, please use MathJax, it make reading the math much easier. :)

Comment: @Lovsovs yup it is N+M,sorry typing mistake,let me edit.

Comment: Not that it's worth much, but there is a graph-theoretical way to formulate it: Given a (possibly disconnected) graph of $N+M$ vertices, color $N$ vertices green and $M$ vertices orange so that the number of neighboring pairs of vertices with different colors is as small as possible.

Comment: @Arthur Will try it,Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is equal to the problem called [graph partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition).

Let every child be a vertex $v$ and every chosen pair be an edge $e$ in graph $G$.
To find apple and orange distribution between children is to find a partition of the graph vertex set $V(G)$ into 2 parts $V_1$ and $V_2$ such as $|V_1|=N$, $|V_2|=M$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$,
while minimizing the number of edges between parts ( edges $(v,u)\in E : v \in V_1$ and $u \in V_2$ ).
The minimization of this edge number will minimize the number of pairs that have different fruits in it.

[image]

Also, the [graph bisection problem](http://tracer.lcc.uma.es/problems/bisect/bisect.htm) which is known to be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness)  can be reduced to your problem, so your problem is NP-hard too. (Proof: Let $N = M$)

So, if you want to find an algorithm for your problem you can use algorithms for graph partitioning. [This survey](http://www.qucosa.de/fileadmin/data/qucosa/documents/5027/data/sfb97-27.pdf) can help you to find a better one for your needs.